# Uncentering a css dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, navbar

Sorry, my bad, was really tired of trying to figure out the issue. So lemme rephrase the question - "How do i make drop-down menu appear below specific item of my centered horizontal menu". ( I've changed the code a bit)

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 4</a>
      <ul id="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">sublink1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">sublink2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS of centered .menu

```
#nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline;
}

#nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-family: "oswald", sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(107, 163, 252, 0.28);
}
```

Comment: if my answer below works for you please mark it as accepted answer, otherwise let me know if it's something different that you needed.

Answer (score 1):

just add

```
ul#dropdown
{
    padding: 0px;
}
```

see jsfiddle here :  https://jsfiddle.net/yxLzbkL3/

edit fyi : if the padding is not specified the user-agent styling from your browser will auto indent multiple lists using padding.

Comment: I still don't get it, which specific item??

Comment: um.. how do i make ul#dropdown appear below #nav(link4)?

Comment: @bibabup0120: Y can't u use something like a select-option, and beautify the same. https://jsfiddle.net/1yhzo7nk/

Comment: You mean above link5? ie. above its parent?